# Shortcut for making pdf in Texshop

Tags: texshop

I just downloaded Texshop and I do not if it exist keyboard shortcut for making pdf. I worked in Texmaker and there, when I wanted to look at pdf version of the document, I did "ctrl+F1" and the document had appeared. But in Texshop I must click with mouse to the "Typeset" button.

Anyone know how to make pdf via keyboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All menu items in the Mac can have key commands associated to them. But TeXShop assigns most of the basic ones for you. If you use the application menu bar (not the one in the document window) you can see which functions have keyboard shortcuts. For your specific case the command is Command-T.

There is also quite a bit of Help available on both TeXShop itself and TeX/LaTeX more generally. You should first start by exploring the Help menu from within TeXShop:

[image: Help Menu]

Answer (score 7):

Typeset: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

New to LaTeX myself, so I was surprised that converting to a PDF (or another document) is called "Typeset".

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very useful